# Mysql_fetch_array in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have such a problem. I write:

```
$id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='video'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($id)){
        echo "Id = " .$row['id'];
    }
```

But I get such an error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in .

How to solve this? Thanks

Comment: ["`get_results` ... returns the entire query result as an array, or NULL on no result. Each element of this array corresponds to one row of the query result and, like get_row, can be an object, an associative array, or a numbered array."](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results)

Answer (score 5):

Here `$wpdb->get_results` will fetch associative array of values ... multiple values

either you need to loop through each of them using

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='video'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());    
if (count($results) > 0) {
    $display_row = null;
    foreach ($results as $res) {
         echo "id - " . $res->id;
    }
}
```

or if you're expecting only one row, then try this

```
$result = $wpdb->get_row($sql);
echo "id - "$result->id;
```